# issue to login on azure cli with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-cli

I tried to login with commands `azure cli` on `python`, but i have a issue.

the script code is:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'a1bc23d4-e5fg-6hi7-8901-23456j7kl8mn',
    secret = '112233445566',
    tenant = 'z0y987x-6543-2w1v-0987-6u5t4s32109r'
   )
```

> `msrest.except ions.AuthenticationError: , AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"ZZBXQH1775: Tenant 'z0y987x-6543-2w1v-0987-6u5t4s32109r' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.`

i use visual studio code to work

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue with a wrong `tenant id`, if I use the correct one, it works. Also, there is no active subscription in my tenant.

[image]

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find your app and copy the `tenant id` as below, then use it to try the code again.

[image]

Comment: didn't work for me, but i tried with subprocess then works

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my issue** using a subprocess,this subprocess call the shell and then send the command az cli

For example:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE
bckp = Popen('az sql db list -s sqlserver --resource-group MYResourceGroup -o table',  shell=True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = bckp.stdout.read().decode("ascii") 
print(text)

with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

This code works for me, I hope helpfull for you!!

Comment: The code in this solution is totally different from the original code, even if it solved your issue, it will not be helpful for others. Per my test, my solution 100% works. If it did not work for you, I think you should do something wrong.